# Everything VoidTools can't find pdflatex.exe

Tags: everything

I installed Miktex (https://miktex.org/), which has a bin folder

MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64

There are files in it such as pdflatex.exe which Everything can't find. It can find other files such as miktex-pdftex.exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you suspect that the disk search index of Everything is incomplete,
you may rebuild it:

- Enter menu *Tools > Options...*
- Click on "Indexes" on the left
- Click the button "Force Rebuild".

Note that re-indexing all the disks can take some appreciable time.